# Icone da aplicação não aparece

Tags: android, android-manifest

Estou fazendo uma aplicação, mas quando eu instalo ela no meu celular, o icone não aparece.
Não faço ideia do que possa ser, o `ic_laucher` está la nas pastas de drawable.

Oque pode ser?

#### Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TelaInicial"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tela_inicial" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Print do menubar**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Como esta seu Manifest?

Comment: atualizei com o manifest

Comment: Eu recomendaria tirar o atributo `logo` da `Activity`, porque o próprio logo do `application` já funciona.

Comment: mesmo sem não aparece

Comment: Remova o android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" da activity de baixo e testa.

Comment: Você poderia mostrar o style ? pode ser que você tenha estendido algum estilo que não possua o logo ou alguma configuração sobrescreva isso.

Comment: Você quer que apareça seu ícone onde?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente isto no **mainfest.xml**. Troque o nome da imagem para 'appicon':

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/appicon" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.droid.MEUAPP">
```

...

Ou isto, com suporte para **appcompat-v7 action bar**, em uma atividade:

```
getActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
```

Comment: minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 21

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);`assim aparece o icone mais muito grande e só na tela que colocar este codigo

Comment: Manda um print do seu menu bar. Acho que você mexeu em alguma coisa e retirou do padrão da versão do SDK.

Comment: E dependendo do aparelho, não aparecerá o ícone, pois depende da versão do android em questão.

Comment: mais outros aplicativos que eu já fiz e os que uso neste celular aparecem o icone , print esta la em cima

Comment: Editei a resposta.