# como fazer para que no icone da aplicação apareça no action bar?

Tags: android, actionbar, icons

por default era para aparecer mas não esta aparecendo
achei esta pergunta [Icone da aplicação não aparece](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/50090/icone-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-aparece) mas a resposta não me atendeu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o método `setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()` para visualizar o espaço do botão home:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Depois o método `setIcon()` para definir o ícone no qual você pretende visualizar:

```
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Veja essa [resposta no SO gringo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451433/2570426).